# More Specific Linker Error in Xcode 4

Tags: xcode, gcc, ide, linker

I'm having some trouble, and getting `Command /Developer/Cocotron/1.0/Linux/i386/gcc-4.3.1/bin/i386-ubuntu-linux-gcc failed with exit code 1` in the link stage. Now, I may be a crazy person, but I seem to recall being able to get something a little more specific in Xcode 3? If I recall correctly, I used to get this sort of helpful warning:

`warning: libpulse-simple.so.0, needed by /Developer/Cocotron/1.0/Linux/ 
i386/Frameworks//libSDL-1.2.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath- 
link)`

But now I seem to get only a "failed with exit code 1", which is not helpful at all in trying to debug. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it's not strictly "in Xcode", I discovered that one can just copy the `ld` command straight out of Xcode's warning tab and run it in Terminal, and thus get the detailed errors straight from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

In the [image] tab, you can see all your issues. Click on it this specific issue, you'll see the detail.

Comment: I've gotten that far--that's what shows me "failed with exit code 1". I swear I had more specific errors in Xcode 3, ones that listed explicitly which libraries were having trouble linking.

Comment: It really depends of the problem you're facing… Maybe it's not about a library not linking…

Comment: Changing which libraries I'm linking to causes it to build and run. I've edited the question with an example of the desired warning.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the -all_load  flag gave me a more specific linker output and the library symbols it was missing.   ( this is in Build Settings under 'Other Linker Flags' )

With the -all_load flag set, the linker just spit out the very useless "Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-g++-4.2 failed with exit code 1"

Comment: Thanks; that looked promising. Unfortunately, -all_load is not included in Other Linker Flags in this project, so that isn't the problem.

Comment: okay, sorry to hear that; I came upon your question here searching about this very same problem.  In any case, I also recall better linker output in XCode 3, and there may be other linker options in XCode 4 to experiment with that will help break down the issue (eg. re-arranging the link order).